# I was getting an error while installing the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools in visual studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, visual-studio-2022, nuget-package

During the installation of the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools NuGet package in the 'TaskTracking' project, two errors were encountered.

Specifically, the package restore process failed, resulting in the rollback of package changes for the 'TaskTracking.API' project.

Additionally, there was an error while attempting to download the package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.8.0.0 from the NuGet package source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/'.

**Error Details:**

**Package Restore Failure:**

- Project Affected: 'TaskTracking.API'
- Error Message: Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes.
- Severity: Error

**Failed Package Download:**

- Package Name: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.8.0.0
- Package Source: 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/'
- Error Message: Failed to download package. Access to the path is denied.
- Severity: Error

**Resolution Steps Attempted:**

- Checked permissions to ensure proper access to the specified path.
- Verified network connection stability and ensured the absence of any blocking issues.
- Temporarily disabled firewall and antivirus software to rule out interference with package downloads.
- Confirmed correct configuration and enabled status of the NuGet package source.
- Cleared the NuGet cache using the command nuget locals all -clear.
- Ensured sufficient disk space availability.
- Attempted to install a different version of the package to isolate the issue.
- Checked for and applied updates to the NuGet Package Manager.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLoQl.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKeWw.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCOV9.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YMBz.png)

Comment: @S Gowtham, based on your error picture, it seems that your project is Asp.net web api. I make a test to install the related nuget package, but I could not reproduce your problem.  I guess that your computer firewall may do some limitations.  You could try to enter website https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/ in your browser to see if you can access it.